# Tensorflow Check failed: status == CUDNN_STATUS_SUCCESS (7 vs. 0)Failed to set cuDNN stream

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, keras, gpu

When I run my tensorflow keras model it will sometimes stop after an epoch and throw the following error:

```
tensorflow/stream_executor/dnn.cc:613] CUDNN_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED
in tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc(1867): 'cudnnRNNForwardTraining( cudnn.handle(), rnn_desc.handle(), model_dims.max_seq_length, input_desc.handles(), input_data.opaque(), input_h_desc.handle(), input_h_data.opaque(), input_c_desc.handle(), input_c_data.opaque(), rnn_desc.params_handle(), params.opaque(), output_desc.handles(), output_data->opaque(), output_h_desc.handle(), output_h_data->opaque(), output_c_desc.handle(), output_c_data->opaque(), workspace.opaque(), workspace.size(), reserve_space.opaque(), reserve_space.size())'
2020-06-27 17:19:45.741256: F tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:189] Check failed: status == CUDNN_STATUS_SUCCESS (7 vs. 0)Failed to set cuDNN stream.
```

Im using the GPU version of tensorflow and it has worked without problems up until about 3 days ago when it began giving me this error. I also have the following callbacks in my model so that it saves checkpoints and epochs locally. Please note I am using Autokeras thus why the nodes have the ak. library prefix. However it works just like keras, it just automatically tries to find the best set of hyperparameters when running the .fit function.

```
input_node = ak.Input()
#output_node1 = ak.Normalization()(input_node)
output_node1 = ak.RNNBlock(return_sequences=True,
                           layer_type='lstm')(input_node)
output_node2 = ak.RNNBlock(return_sequences=True,
                           layer_type='lstm')(output_node1)
output_node3 = ak.RNNBlock(return_sequences=True,
                           layer_type='lstm')(output_node2)
output_node4 = ak.RNNBlock(layer_type='lstm')(output_node3)
output_node5 = ak.DenseBlock()(output_node4)
output_node = ak.Merge()(
    [output_node1, output_node2, output_node3, output_node4, output_node5])
output_nodefinal = ak.ClassificationHead()(output_node)

my_callbacks = [tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=15, restore_best_weights=True, monitor="val_accuracy", mode="auto"),
                tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath="D:\AutoKerasProject\TimeseriesCallbackModel\TimeseriesCallbackModel", save_weights_only=True, monitor='val_accuracy', mode='auto', save_best_only=True)]

classifier = ak.AutoModel(
    inputs=input_node, outputs=output_nodefinal, max_trials=500, directory="D:\AutoKerasProject\TimeseriesModel", overwrite=True)
```

My PC and software specs are as follows

```
PC Specs:
Windows 8.1
GTX 1060 6GB
Intel i7-4770

Software Specs:
Nvidia Geforce Experience Driver 451.81
CuDNN 7.6.5 (windows 7 version)
Cuda 10.1.243
Conda Python 3.6.10
Tensorflow 2.2.0
```

Comment: Could you provide more details? Especially what is you TensorFlow version, which OS do you run, your GPU details and ideally some code (reproducible example) you are running.

Comment: PC Specs:
Windows 8.1
GTX 1060 6GB
Intel i7-4770

Software Specs:
Nvidia Geforce Experience Driver 451.81
CudNN 10.1 (windows 7 version)
Cuda 10.1.243
Conda Python 3.6.10
Tensorflow 2.2.0

Comment: Thanks for updates. Are you sure with cuDNN version? There is no `10.1` version, you should use `7.6.5` with current version of your TF. Are you using update 2 for Cuda (https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-10.1-download-archive-update2)? And I would recommend using Windows 8.1 version as this is your OS.

Comment: Sorry, I obviously meant that I am using version 7.6.5 of CuDNN that support the 10.1 version of cuda. My bad.
Regarding update 2 for Cuda, then I am actually not sure, I want to say no because that's how I remember it, but my nvcc --version gives me the following: nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2019 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Jul_28_19:12:52_Pacific_Daylight_Time_
Cuda compilation tools, release 10.1, V10.1.243

Comment: That should be correct. The only thing I would recommend at the moment is to reinstall your environment (Cuda + cuDNN + TF). I am dealing with similar problem I will get back to you if I find something.

Comment: I've reinstalled tensorflow, cuda and cuDNN but with no luck so far.

Comment: @Nerxis any luck? Im getting kind of desperate here.

Comment: Still the same, it seems like some specific issue in combination of TF + cuDNN + Windows. For me, the behaviour is quite random (sometimes it failes immediately, sometimes it lasts several epochs), is it the same for you?

Comment: Yep, there isnt an consistent time for when it stops, as said it can last up to 30 min or stop after very few epochs.
FML I spent so long fetching and appending data and making a model that actually runs only for it to somehow out of the blue to stop working...

Comment: @Nerxis I've solved the issue, check the answer on the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the cause to the error, you need to downgrade your Nvidia drivers to version 431.36. Everything above that makes tensorflow crash in above mentioned manner.

Comment: How did you manage to downgrade? I have almost the same GPU (GTX 2070) but having troubles to downgrade (rollback does not work and I could not find driver version on nvidia drivers page)..

Comment: I use a program called DDU

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why was this downgrading needed? It seems it works for me as well. But don't know why.

Comment: Basicly LSTM's become kind of wonky with the newer versions of nvidias drivers. As to the technical details about it, then I don't really know.

Comment: I downgraded my driver then I got other issues on other code snippets..Not a perfect solution

Answer (score 2):

For anybody who's still getting this error: Downgrading is **not** needed. Only these lines are:

```py
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and realised that it is due to my tensor flow version.
Try this snippet.

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf

tf.disable_v2_behavior()  #disable for tensorFlow V2
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
```